# 3 square roots in side each other equation :

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

$$\sqrt{25-(x+1)\sqrt{4-(x-11)\sqrt{1+(x-6)(x-8)}}} = \frac{(9x-18-x^2)}{2} $$
Find (x)

I tried to take the square to the both sides but i couldn't continue,,
 can you help me ??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Just try calculating: Start with the term

$1+(x-6)(x-8)$

and see if you can take the square root of that and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand

Comment: @SuheirAlSabbah This is a good hint. You can rewrite this expression as $(x-7)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that $9x-18-x^2\ge 0 \quad \implies x \in [3,6]$

Then, start from the most bottom square root and try factoring it (and hoping it can be square root-ed). Make sure it is positive in $[3,6]$, so that the constraint is satisfied.

For example $\sqrt{1+(x-6)(x-8)} = \sqrt{(x-7)^2}=|x-7|=7-x$ (as $x-7 \ngeq 0 \quad\forall x\in[3,6])$

And then continue by tackling the next square root in the same manner.

---

$\sqrt{25-(x+1)\sqrt{4-(x-11)\sqrt{1+(x-6)(x-8)}}} \\
=\sqrt{25-(x+1)\sqrt{4-(x-11)\sqrt{(x-7)^2}}}\\
=\sqrt{25-(x+1)\sqrt{4-(x-11)(7-x)}}\\
=\sqrt{25-(x+1)\sqrt{(x-9)^2}}\\
=\sqrt{25-(x+1)(9-x)}\\
=\sqrt{(x-4)^2}\\
=|x-4|$

(as we don't know whether $x\ge4$ or $x<4$)

Comment: Can you solve all the question so I can understand better?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: You do realize why $9x^2-18-x^2 \ge0$?